# Pytorch: how to repeat a parameter matrix into a bigger one along both dimensions?

Tags: pytorch

What is the simplest syntax to transform 2D parameter tensor

```
A   B
C   D
```

into

```
A  A  B  B
A  A  B  B
C  C  D  D
C  C  D  D
```

Note they are parameter tensors, so I need autograd to back propagate gradient from latter into former.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found a numpy.repeat()-like function in latest pytorch (1.1), but it is needed to be called twice:

```
z = x.repeat_interleave(2,dim=0).repeat_interleave(2,dim=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

using einops (same code works with numpy and pytorch):

```
z = einops.repeat(x, 'i j -> (i 2) (j 2)')
```